# handling m-audio mobilepre USB outputs in Apple logic

Tags: live

how can I redirect a single instrument in Apple logic to different outputs on my mobilepre? I would like to send all my track instruments to mixer and just the track where I have prepared a click sound to my drummer who will be using ear buds.

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you want to do. You have pre-recorded tracks, and you want to have the drummer lay down another track in sync with the click? You have pre-recorded tracks and these will be played back with the drummer performing live to the click? Or something else? The MobilePre manual seems to say that you have exactly two outs, with the headphone jack mirroring outputs 1 and 2.

Comment: We have everything recorded and the drummer will play live

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best you can do with the MobilePre is to have two mono channels: click on one and tracks on the other. This is probably not what you want.

I think you're going to want an interface with at least 4 independent outs: one L/R pair for the PA tracks, and one L/R pair for the drummer getting the click. Depending on how loud the PA is and how isolating the ear buds are, you may or may not need to mix a little of the tracks into the drummer's click track to help him/her keep his/her place.

A Fast Track Pro should be able to give you the two independent output pairs; the Fast Track can't.